# Can't drag-drop from Windows Ubuntu VirtualBox machine

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Can't copy file from Windows11 host to Ubuntu 23.04 virtual machine running on VirtualBox 7.0.14. Got error "Drag and drop operation from host to guest failed"

I have installed Guest Additions. But found menu that offers to install updates for them. Update install fails.

How to solve that?

[image]

Comment: Have you installed [Guest Additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html) ?

Comment: Yes, I have installed Guest Additions. But found menu that offers to install updates for them. Update install fails.

Comment: Please add these details to your post.